# iOS Which is better design comparing passing the whole class to view or setting piece by piece

Tags: ios, objective-c, loose-coupling

I have a `User` class has some properties such as name, email, location. And I have another class
 called `Post` which has some properties such as `title`, `content`and `poster` that is a instance of `User`.

There is a ViewController, inside the view controller there is a `PostDetailView` which is used to show post details. Now the view controller has a post object and I need to pass some values to `PostDetailView`. I have two options:

1. Pass the whole `post` object through initializer, which means `PostDetailView` has a method -initWithFrame:post. Once the view get the post object, it can get every data inside the post.
2. `PostDetailView` has some setter method such as `setTitle:`, `setContent`, `setPosterName`, etc. Initializer only initialize frame of view, and then using setters to pass value.

Option 1 can save lots of work in view controller but may increase coupling. Option 2 has better structure (I thought), but need additional work in both view and view controller. Therefore, my question is which one is better in terms of architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In favor of good design and architecture it make sense to type a little more and have views decoupled from model. One technic that I've used to is to design view with properties of primitive types (String, Number etc.) and create a category for the view that has a method to configure itself with a model object of a particular type.

You can read more about this here: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html
They talk about table view but approach can be used for any view and model with mediating controller.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a model object to the view does increase the coupling unnecessarily. Setting the individual fields is better, because the binding logic is in the controller.

A third option is to build a class that contains only the data needed by the view, and pass an object of this class to the view, instead of passing the entire `Post`:

```
@interface PostViewData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *content;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyUser *poster;
@end
```

Although the controller is still required to house a view-specific logic, the view remains insulated from the model, and the code becomes explicit about the content of the view-specific data.

Comment: This is known as a "view model".